# Error to create a a trigger

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that everytime that insert a new data in my table tb_produto_parent, I need to update the columm cod_prod add one more.

Follow the trigger :

```
DELIMITER $$

create trigger trgAdicionaUm after insert
on tb_produto_parent
for each row

BEGIN
    select cod_prod from tb_produto_parent;
update 
    tb_produto_parent set cod_prod = cod_prod +1;       
END;
```

When I try to execute the code, MySQL show me a error :

```
Error Code: 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger.
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems with your code

1. you can't use `SELECT` on it own in a trigger because a trigger doesn't return a resultset to the client
2. you can't use DML statements (`UPDATE` in your case) on the same table (`tb_produto_parent`) on which you have your trigger in MySQL. Therefore even if you fix the first problem you still won't be able to update any row in `tb_produto_parent` within the trigger.

The only thing you can do in MySQL trigger is to alter values of columns of a row being inserted by using a `BEFORE` event for a trigger.

A possible solution is to use a stored procedure instead.

Answer (score 0):

`Error Code: 1415 Not allowed to return a result set from a trigger.`

Looking at your trigger:

```
BEGIN
    select cod_prod from tb_produto_parent;
update 
    tb_produto_parent set cod_prod = cod_prod +1;       
END;
```

It would seem the `select` statement is the cause of this error. Remove it.

Comment: Adding to what @mah said, you are returning result set in that SELECT statement, it looks like you need only one value. So, please modify that